# To install or not install 12.04, yet? 

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I am happy user of Ubuntu 11.10 (32bit) desktop, it works well in my laptop (HP dv6700) and I have installed everything I need on it. Each time I move to a newer version, for example from 9.04 to 11.10, I just feel it is too much afford and many times things doesn't work I expected: system crash, no nvidia actualized drives,.

My intention is to install Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) desktop version, but I would like to hear about your experiences, either good or bad, in changing version to this new version. I just feel it is too early to move, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still beta quality software, in my opinion. But then again, I'm known for being very critical when it comes to software I'm using daily. It is much more stable than Ubuntu 11.10, I have experienced no overheatings this time, and my battery life has been multiplied by 3. Unity 2D finally is as good as on par with regular Unity.

Overall, Ubuntu 12.04 has gained some great improvements. I'd suggest you switch over to Ubuntu 12.04, or if you really need stability, wait for Ubuntu 12.04.1. Don't *upgrade* though, just backup everything and do a fresh installation (A regular installation! Not with experimental headache software like Wubi!).

Comment: Upgrading 32bit to 64bit requires full install anyways. I usually make a full disk image using `dd` before installing version upgrades which I keep in a safe place. Never needed it, but that way I'm sure I can always revert to the old situation.

Comment: it is a good idea to make the full image, thanks